# calling a viewController problem

Tags: iphone

Hi everyone i need help i added a new view to a recent project and when i call it i get an error in my header file. here is a snippet of it

```
#import "HowtoPlay.h"
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface SplashViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {
    id myCreator;
    SettingsWindow *settingsWindow;
    HowtoPlay *HowtoPlay1;
    ADBannerView *bannerView;


}
```

im having the problem with the HowtoPlay *HowtoPlay1; line the error message says ( expected specific qualifier list before " HowtoPlay" ) but in all my efforts cannot get it to work does anyone know whats going on? the line before it SettingsWindow *settingsWindow; works just fine and i call them both the same way in my implementation file.

Comment: sorry about the clutter i didn't mean for the code to look like that,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure abt it...But remove `#import "HowtoPlay.h"` and put `@class HowtoPlay`...

Comment: That eliminated my error but my project now exits as soon as it launches?

Comment: i am so sorry guys it was a problem in interface builder i forgot to take some outlets off two buttons i wasn't using anymore as outlets in my .h.